# What is the mechanism of aspirin as an anticoagulant?

Tags: hematology, medicine

I understand that aspirin prevents blood clots from forming by interfering with the clotting action. I want to know at which stage aspirin interferes with clot forming and what really happens in the process. I've used google to understand this but did not find a satisfactory answer.

For example, [here](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/heart-disease/in-depth/daily-aspirin-therapy/art-20046797#:%7E:text=Aspirin%20interferes%20with%20your%20blood%27s,blood%20vessel%20to%20stop%20bleeding.) I found:

> How can aspirin prevent a heart attack?
> Aspirin interferes with your blood's clotting action. When you bleed, your blood's clotting cells, called platelets, build up at the site of your wound. The platelets help form a plug that seals the opening in your blood vessel to stop bleeding.

> But this clotting can also happen within the vessels that supply your heart with blood. If your blood vessels are already narrowed from atherosclerosis — the buildup of fatty deposits in your arteries — a fatty deposit in your vessel lining can burst.

> Then, a blood clot can quickly form and block the artery. This prevents blood flow to the heart and causes a heart attack. Aspirin therapy reduces the clumping action of platelets — possibly preventing a heart attack.

Every site I visited had descriptions like this (mostly concentrated on the medicinal side). I want to know what aspirin does that prevents blood clotting at the chemical level, which I haven't been able to find.

Comment: I found another question and answer here that already seems to answer your question, so I've marked it as a duplicate. There's no penalty for a duplicate question, it will help people who see your question first in search find the answer they want and helps us keep things orderly.

Comment: thank you very much. stay safe